# MySql aggregate by different initial values on other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure as follows

```
| user_id | value | date       |
|---------|-------|------------|
| 1       | 5     | 2017-09-01 |
| 2       | 6     | 2017-09-01 |
| 1       | 1     | 2017-09-02 |
| 1       | 2     | 2017-09-03 |
| 2       | 9     | 2017-09-02 |
| 1       | 3     | 2017-09-04 |
| 2       | 5     | 2017-09-04 |
| 2       | 5     | 2017-09-05 |
| 1       | 1     | 2017-09-05 |
| 1       | 5     | 2017-09-06 |
| 1       | 6     | 2017-09-07 |
| 1       | 3     | 2017-09-08 |
| 1       | 4     | 2017-09-09 |
| 2       | 6     | 2017-09-06 |
| 1       | 1     | 2017-09-10 |
```

I have another table where initial cutoff date for user_ids are given like

```
| user_id | date       |
|---------|------------|
| 1       | 2017-09-04 |
| 2       | 2017-09-05 |
```

The final cutoff date for all the user is 2017-09-08

I want to get the sum of values aggregated by user_id

What I have tried is

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(value) as Total 
FROM table 
WHERE date >= $DATE and date <= '2017-09-08'
GROUP BY user_id
```

I am stuck how should I deal with $DATE as it is variable for each user

The solution in the case should be

```
| user_id | Total      |
|---------|------------|
| 1       | 18         |
| 2       | 11         |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have table names as `users` and `cutoff`. `cutoff` having cutoff date for each user. Try this and let me know if it works or not.

```
select u.user_id,sum(u.value) Total 
from users u join cutoff c on u.user_id=c.user_id and (u.date>=c.date and u.date<='2017-09-08') 
group by u.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT x.user_id, SUM(x.value) as Total 
FROM table x 
WHERE x.date >= (select date from table2 where user_id = x.user_id) 
and x.date <= '2017-09-08'
GROUP BY x.user_id
```

Comment: Correlated subqueries are not implemented very well in MySQL, joins are almost always preferable.

Comment: Not in this case. The subquery is very simple.
Do a sample of 1: M is less advantageous for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Using where exists

```
SELECT a.user_id, SUM(a.value) as Total 
FROM table1 a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table2 b
  WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id 
  AND a.date >= b.date and a.date <= '2017-09-08'
)
GROUP BY user_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/786f6e/9)

OR using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT a.user_id,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.date >= b.date and a.date <= '2017-09-08' 
    THEN a.value 
    ELSE 0 
    END) as Total 
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
GROUP BY user_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/786f6e/10)

Comment: The expected answer should be as stated in question (18, 11). From this query I am getting (23,11)

Comment: @JayChakra my bad, it was misplacement of column of table b, now corrected